# Python one-liner to print every file in the current directory

Tags: python, cygwin, cmd, pipe

How can I make the following one liner print every file through Python?

```
python -c "import sys;print '>>',sys.argv[1:]" | dir *.*
```

Specifically would like to know how to pipe into a python -c.
DOS or Cygwin responses accepted.

Comment: Seems like there would be a better way to do that than using Python...

Comment: this is not really on liner!!! unless you follow a very laaaaax definition of a line of code, where empty lines are counted too!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?? dir *.* already lists them all, so what's the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read data piped **into** a Python script by reading sys.stdin. For example:

```
ls -al | python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.readlines()"
```

It is not entirely clear what you want to do (maybe I am stupid). The confusion comes from your example which is piping data out of a python script.

Answer (score 6):

```
python -c "import os; print os.listdir('.')"
```

If you want to apply some formatting like you have in your question,

```
python -c "import os; print '\n'.join(['>>%s' % x for x in os.listdir('.')])"
```

If you want to use a pipe, use `xargs`:

```
ls | xargs python -c "import sys; print '>>', sys.argv[1:]"
```

or backticks:

```
python -c "import sys; print '>>', sys.argv[1:]" `ls`
```

Comment: Thanks, would like to know how to pipe though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print *all* files:

```
find . -type f
```

If you want to print only the current directory's files

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1
```

If you want to include the ">>" before each line

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs -L 1 echo ">>"
```

If you don't want the space between ">>" and $path from echo

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs -L 1 printf ">>%s\n"
```

This is all using cygwin, of course.

Comment: +1 - python is nice (I'm a fan), but sometimes there are tools just built to do the job already :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
ls | python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.read()"
```

just read stdin as normal for pipes

Comment: no point inherently, but it's a starting point for slightly more complex and possibly useful commands.

Answer (score 2):

> would like to know how to pipe though

You had the pipe the wrong way round, if you wanted to feed the output of ‘dir’ into Python, ‘dir’ would have to be on the left. eg.:

```
dir "*.*" | python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write('>>%s\n' % line) for line in sys.stdin]"
```

(The hack with the list comprehension is because you aren't allowed a block-introducing ‘for’ statement on one line after a semicolon.)

Clearly the Python-native solution (‘os.listdir’) is much better in practice.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically would like to know how to pipe into a python -c

see [cobbal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613007/613134#613134)

piping through a program is transparent from the program's point of view, all the program knows is that it's getting input from the standard input stream

Generally speaking, a shell command of the form

```
A | B
```

redirects the output of A to be the input of B

so if A spits "asdf" to standard output, then B gets "asdf" into its standard input

the standard input stream in python is [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

Comment: One thing kinda bothers me though. Why do you want to use `python -c`?

Comment: to avoid writing a py file saving it and then running though cmd line.